# Hive Update and Delete

Tags: hive, odbc, unixodbc

I am using Hive 1.0.0 Version and Hadoop 2.6.0 and Cloudera ODBC Driver. I am trying to Update and Delete the data in the hive database from Cloudera HiveOdbc Driver it throws an error. Here is my error.

What i have done ?

**CREATE:**

```
create database geometry;

create table odbctest (EmployeeID Int,FirstName String,Designation String, Salary Int,Department String) 
clustered by (department)
into 3 buckets
stored as orcfile
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
```

> Table created.

**INSERT:**

```
insert into table geometry.odbctest values(10,'Hive','Hive',0,'B');
```

By passing the above query the data is inserting into database.

**UPDATE:**

When i am trying to Update the following error is getting

```
update geometry.odbctest set salary = 50000 where employeeid = 10;
```

> SQL>  update geometry.odbctest set salary = 50000 where employeeid = 10;
>
> [S1000][Cloudera][HiveODBC] (55) Insert operation is not support for
>   table: HIVE.geometry.odbctest
>
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLPrepare

**DELETE:**

When i am trying to Delete the following error is getting

```
delete from geometry.odbctest where employeeid=10;
```

> SQL> delete from geometry.odbctest where employeeid=10;
>
> [S1000][Cloudera][HiveODBC] (55) Insert operation is not support for table: HIVE.geometry.odbctest
>
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLPrepare

Can anyone help me out,

Answer (score 3):

You have done a couple of required steps properly:

- ORC format
- Bucketed table

A likely cause would be: one or more of the following hive settings were not included:

> These configuration parameters must be set appropriately to turn on
>   transaction support in Hive:

```
hive.support.concurrency – true
hive.enforce.bucketing – true
hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode – nonstrict
hive.txn.manager – org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager
hive.compactor.initiator.on – true (for exactly one instance of the Thrift metastore service)
hive.compactor.worker.threads – a positive number on at least one instance of the Thrift metastore service
```

The full requirements for transaction support are here:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

If you have verified the above settings are in place then do a

```
describe extended odbctest;
```

To evaluate its transaction related characteristics.

Comment: I had update all the acid properties in hive-site.xml when i am working on hive it's working fine

Comment: @SreeEedupuganti  So did you find my post helpful and/or correct? I.e. did you use any of the properties shown here in your solution?

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  I have all the properties set that you listed and the table is orc, transactional and bucketed.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @craigtb  I can not assure a complete answer, but if you give a gist with the output of "describe extended <yourtable>;"  i can give it a shot.

Comment: @javadba the extended desc is too long.  Is there a way i can send it to you ?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same issue when connecting to Hive 1.2 using the Simba ODBC driver distributed by Cloudera (v 2.5.12.1005 64-bit). After verifying everything in javadba's post, I did some additional digging and found the problem to be a bug in the ODBC driver.

I was able to resolve the issue by using the Progress DataDirect driver, and it looks like the version of the driver distributed by hortonworks works as well (links to both solutions below).

https://www.progress.com/data-sources/apache-hive-drivers-for-odbc-and-jdbc
http://hortonworks.com/hdp/addons/

Hope that helps anyone who may still be struggling!

Answer (score 0):

You should not think about Hive as a regular RDBMS, Hive is better suited for batch processing over very large sets of immutable data.

Here is what you can find[enter link description here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial)

> Hadoop is a batch processing system and Hadoop jobs tend to have high
>   latency and incur substantial overheads in job submission and
>   scheduling. As a result - latency for Hive queries is generally very
>   high (minutes) even when data sets involved are very small (say a few
>   hundred megabytes). As a result it cannot be compared with systems
>   such as Oracle where analyses are conducted on a significantly smaller
>   amount of data but the analyses proceed much more iteratively with the
>   response times between iterations being less than a few minutes. Hive
>   aims to provide acceptable (but not optimal) latency for interactive
>   data browsing, queries over small data sets or test queries.
>
> Hive is not designed for online transaction processing and does not
>   offer real-time queries and row level updates. It is best used for
>   batch jobs over large sets of immutable data (like web logs).

Answer (score -1):

As of now Hive does not support Update and Delete Operations on the data in HDFS.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

Comment: That was changed in Hive 1.0